# Angular js ng-show doesn't work with native Math expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

This doesn't work (div never appears):

```
<div ng-show="parseFloat(vehicle.pricing) > 1">
```

This DOES work:

```
<div ng-show="vehicle.pricing > 1">
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've created the parseFloat function on the $scope/scope it won't be available to the DOM. The only things available are comparisons and things you attach to the $scope/scope.

Look into the filters provided by angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter there might be one you can use.

Comment: @Mathew even native JS functions? So I would add something like this in the controller?  `$scope.parseFloat = function(x) { return parseFloat(x); }`

Comment: Yeah, native functions aren't going to be there, but you are right, doing what you just suggested will work.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include a link to some angular filters.